# How to plot a regression line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, regression

I cannot make a proper regression line. My a1 value is supposed to be positive, but it is negative. If I skip the mask part then my a1, b1, c1 values become NaN.

```
kwargs = dict(delimiter = '\t',\
         skip_header = 0,\
         missing_values = 'NaN',\
         converters = {0:matplotlib.dates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')},\
         dtype = float,\
         names = True,\
         )

ratingcats = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\ker\Documents\Discharge_and_stageheight_Catsop.txt',**kwargs)

dis_rat = ratingcats['discharge']   #change names of columns
stage_rat = ratingcats['stage']

#create regression line and mask NaN
dis_ratM = np.ma.masked_array(dis_rat,mask=np.isnan(dis_rat)).compressed()
stage_ratM = np.ma.masked_array(stage_rat,mask=np.isnan(dis_rat)).compressed()

a1,b1,c1 = polyfit(dis_ratM, stage_ratM, 2)

discharge_pred = polyval([a1,b1,c1],stage_ratM)

print (a1,b1,c1)

#create scatterplot

matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(stage_rat,dis_rat,color='red',label='Rating curve')
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(stage_ratM,discharge_pred,'r-',label='regression line')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: could you provide your input data for testing?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the polyfit curve a bad fit? The NaN happens most likely because you treat missing_values as NaN.

Comment: @HarryPotfleur yes i can, but is quit big, how do i provide you the data?

Comment: @RobinSpiess it is a bad fit indeed.

Comment: @ToineKerckhoffs I think a picture of the plot would be very helpful in that case.

Comment: @RobinSpiess http://i.stack.imgur.com/SPL7C.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your code a second time I noticed that the arguments for polyfit are in the wrong order. The signature of polyfit is `numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg)`.

Try using

```
a1,b1,c1 = polyfit(stage_ratM, dis_ratM, 2)
```

(Note the swapped order of `stage_ratM`and `dist_ratM`) and see if it works now.

Comment: Thanks it is much better now, but still not good. It looks like there are more lines and the ''a1,b1,c1'' still don't make sens. The point of a regression line is that there is only one line? My data file is huge(half a million values) were the most ''dis_rat" are zero but can correspont to several values of ''stage_rat'' . Seems strange to me this is the problem? here is the graph now:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kvrvS.png

Comment: @ToineKerckhoffs ah yes, sort the data according to the x coordinates (i.e. stage_ratM) before plotting. (Specifically you could use numpy.argsort to get the sorted indices and then use these indices to sort dis_ratM and stage_ratM even before calling polyfit.) And try to plot it with different colors for the regression line and the scatter points, so that it is clear which is which.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the second part, how do i use the indices to sort dis_ratM and stage_ratM?

Comment: @ToineKerckhoffs `sort_ind = np.argsort(stage_ratM)` then `stage_ratM = stage_ratM[sort_ind]` and `dis_ratM = dis_ratM[sort_ind]`

Comment: Sorry one more question, how do i extrapolate this regression line?

Comment: @ToineKerckhoffs Use `discharge_pred = polyval([a1,b1,c1], np.arange(60,100,0.5))` adapt the np.arange parameters as you like.